# JS alert on ajax add to cart for specific product category count in Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce I'm trying to display a JavaScript "Sweet alert" when a specific count of products in the cart from a specific category is reached. Items are added to the cart via AJAX which is why I want to use a JavaScript alert (Sweet alert).

e.g. IF cart contains *5 products* from category *"Bags"* - Display alert.

I have researched and found the following helpful answers and used them to build out my code. However, I am struggling with applying the rule to only *count products from a specific category*.

- [Display a sweet alert on AJAX add to cart for a specific Woocommerce cart product count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025474/counting-cart-items-of-specific-product-category)
- [Counting cart-items of specific product category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50435374/display-a-sweet-alert-on-ajax-add-to-cart-for-a-specific-woocommerce-cart-item-c)

**At the moment, the code below successfully triggers, but only based on the number of products in the cart. It ignores the *product category* rule:**

Loop Through cart items and set the product category counter:

```
// Wordpress Ajax: Get different cart items count
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_checking_items', 'checking_items' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_checking_items', 'checking_items' );
function checking_items() {

  global $woocommerce, $product;
                $i=0;         
                // Set minimum product cart total
                $total_bags = 0;
                $total_shoes = 0;

    if( isset($_POST['added'])){
        // Loop through cart for product category
        foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product ) :
                    if ( has_term( 'bags', 'product_cat', $product['22'] ) ) {
                       $total_bags += $product['quantity'];
                    } else {
                       $total_shoes += $product['quantity'];
                    }
                endforeach;
    }
    die(); // To avoid server error 500
}
```

Using jQuery, if count of category met, display JavaScript alert.

```
 // The Jquery script
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'item_check' );
function item_check() {
    ?>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.20.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        // The Ajax function
        $(document.body).on('added_to_cart', function() {
            console.log('event');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'checking_cart_items',
                    'added' : 'yes'
                },
              //ONLY DISPLAY ALERT IF TOTAL ITEMS IS FROM CATEGORY BAGS
                success: function ($total_bags) {
                    if($total_bags == 5 ){
//DISPLAY JAVASCRIPT ALERT
const toast = swal.mixin({
  toast: true,
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 3000
});
toast({
  type: 'success',
  title: '5 Items Added!'
})
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. you are not returning anything from the checking_items() function

Comment: Do I need to explicitly return the variable?...I tried adding `return $total_bags;` after the IF in the function but didn't seem to change the behaviour of the `checking_items()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some errors and mistakes in your code. Try this revisited code instead:

```
// Wordpress Ajax: Get different cart items count
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_checking_items', 'checking_cart_items' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_checking_items', 'checking_cart_items' );
function checking_cart_items() {
    if( isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] > 0 ){
        // Initialising variables
        $count      = 0;
        $product_id = $_POST['id'];
        $category   = 'bags';
        $category   = 't-shirts';

        // Loop through cart for product category
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            if ( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
               $count += $cart_item['quantity'];
            }
        }

        // Only if the added item belongs to the defined product category
        if( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $_POST['id'] ) )
            echo $count; // Returned value to jQuery
    }

    die(); // To avoid server error 500
}

// The Jquery script
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'items_check' );
function items_check() {
    if(is_checkout()) return; // Except on checkout page
    ?>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.20.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        // wc_add_to_cart_params is required to continue
        if ( typeof wc_add_to_cart_params === 'undefined' )
            return false;

        $(document.body).on( 'added_to_cart', function( event, fragments, cart_hash, $button ) {
            // The Ajax request
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'checking_items',
                    'id'    : $button.data( 'product_id' ) // Send the product ID
                },
              //ONLY DISPLAY ALERT IF TOTAL ITEMS IS FROM CATEGORY BAGS
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log('response: '+response); // Testing: to be removed
                    if(response == 5 ){
                        //DISPLAY JAVASCRIPT ALERT
                        const toast = swal.mixin({
                          toast: true,
                          showConfirmButton: false,
                          timer: 3000
                        });
                        toast({
                          type: 'success',
                          title: '5 Items Added!'
                        })
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

If you look on your browser inspector javascript console, you will see that ajax is working in the right way, returning each time the items count for that specific product category:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec, I've tried the above code, but it doesn't seem to be working for me? The items add to cart successfully, however nothing triggers. I've looked at the inspector and I am getting `admin-ajax.php - 400 Bad Request` I do not get this error when the code is deactivated...I have never seen this error before?

Comment: @TheNattyProfessor I have retested the code just now, and it works perfectly… So there is something else like other code customizations, something in your theme or a plugin that is conflicting.

Comment: Silly mistake, it was just my typo in the code - above example is working now! Just one question, it doesn't take into account if there is a second category? e.g. `IF category == bags, display alert 1....IF category == shoes, display alert 2`

Comment: I have published new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555448/js-alert-on-ajax-add-to-cart-for-multiple-product-categories-count-in-woocommerc) and also upvoted the links in my question here. Thanks for your help :)