# JS alert on ajax add to cart for multiple product categories count in Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce I'm trying to display a JavaScript "Sweet alert" when a specific count of products in the cart from a specific product category is reached, AND another alert when a specific count of products from a secondary category is reached.

Items are added to the cart via AJAX which is why I want to use a JavaScript alert (Sweet alert).

e.g.

1. IF cart contains *5 products* from category "*Bags*" - Display alert
   bags.
2. IF cart contains *5 products* from category "*Shoes*" - Display alert shoes.
3. IF basket *already has 5 bags* and *then 5 shoes are added* - Display alert shoes, but NOT for bags as they are already in the basket

The code below can work for scenario **1** and **2**, but does handle number **3**.

I have been helped with [this answer code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50553666/js-alert-on-ajax-add-to-cart-for-specific-product-category-count-in-woocommerce/50554322?noredirect=1#comment88121664_50554322) to which works for a single product category:

```
// Wordpress Ajax: Get different cart items count
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_checking_items', 'checking_cart_items' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_checking_items', 'checking_cart_items' );
function checking_cart_items() {
    if( isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] > 0 ){
        // Initialising variables
        $count      = 0;
        $product_id = $_POST['id'];
        $category   = 'bags';
        $category   = 't-shirts';

        // Loop through cart for product category
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            if ( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
               $count += $cart_item['quantity'];
//ELSE IF STATEMENT HERE?
            }
        }

        // Only if the added item belongs to the defined product category
        if( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $_POST['id'] ) )
            echo $count; // Returned value to jQuery
    }

    die(); // To avoid server error 500
}

// The Jquery script
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'items_check' );
function items_check() {
    if(is_checkout()) return; // Except on checkout page
    ?>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.20.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        // wc_add_to_cart_params is required to continue
        if ( typeof wc_add_to_cart_params === 'undefined' )
            return false;

        $(document.body).on( 'added_to_cart', function( event, fragments, cart_hash, $button ) {
            // The Ajax request
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'checking_items',
                    'id'    : $button.data( 'product_id' ) // Send the product ID
                },
              //ONLY DISPLAY ALERT IF TOTAL ITEMS IS FROM CATEGORY BAGS
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log('response: '+response); // Testing: to be removed
                    if(response == 5 ){
                        //DISPLAY JAVASCRIPT ALERT
                        const toast = swal.mixin({
                          toast: true,
                          showConfirmButton: false,
                          timer: 3000
                        });
                        toast({
                          type: 'success',
                          title: '5 Items Added!'
                        })
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

How can I handle 2 different product categories?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did those 2 alerts have a different messages (meaning the one for the shoes and the one for bags)… if yes what are they?

Comment: The two alerts are the same...just a different string value shown in the message..e.g. _"You've added 5 bags"_ & _"You've added 5 shoes"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work for 2 different product categories displaying a Sweet alert when 5 items from one of those product categories have been added to cart:

```
// Wordpress Ajax: Get different cart items count
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_checking_items', 'checking_cart_items' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_checking_items', 'checking_cart_items' );
function checking_cart_items() {
    if( isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] > 0 ){
        // Initialising variables
        $counts     = array();
        $product_id = $_POST['id'];
        $categories = array('bags', 'shoes');

        // Loop through cart for product categories count
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            if ( has_term( $categories[0], 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) )
               $counts[0] += $cart_item['quantity'];
            if ( has_term( $categories[1], 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) )
               $counts[1] += $cart_item['quantity'];
        }

        // Return the product category count that belongs to the added item
        if( has_term( $categories[0], 'product_cat', $product_id ) )
            echo json_encode(array( strtoupper($categories[0]) => $counts[0])); // Returned value to jQuery
        if( has_term( $categories[1], 'product_cat', $product_id ) )
            echo json_encode(array( strtoupper($categories[1]) => $counts[1])); // Returned value to jQuery
    }

    die(); // To avoid server error 500
}

// The Jquery script
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'items_check' );
function items_check() {
    if(is_checkout()) return; // Except on checkout page
    ?>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.20.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        // wc_add_to_cart_params is required to continue
        if ( typeof wc_add_to_cart_params === 'undefined' )
            return false;

        $(document.body).on( 'added_to_cart', function( event, fragments, cart_hash, $button ) {
            // The Ajax request
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'checking_items',
                    'id'    : $button.data('product_id') // Send the product ID
                },
              //ONLY DISPLAY ALERT IF TOTAL ITEMS IS FROM CATEGORY BAGS
                success: function (response) {
                    $.each( JSON.parse(response), function( category, count ) {
                        if( count == 5 ){
                            // Display javascript alert
                            const toast = swal.mixin({
                              toast: true,
                              showConfirmButton: false,
                              timer: 3000
                            });
                            toast({
                              type: 'success',
                              title: "You've added 5 "+category+"!"
                            });
                        }
                        // The below line is just for testing: to be removed
                        console.log('category: '+category+' | count: '+count);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: @TheLoicTheAztec Thanks! works perfectly...is there a way to capitalize the category variable which is passed into the alert message? e.g. **You've added 5 BAGS!**

Comment: @TheNattyProfessor First, one thing: [**In HERE, THIS**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50562872/3730754) should be the accepted answer and not the actual one (you can change of accepted answer). Now to get the current product category slug that is returned to jQuery in capitals, it's very simple using `strtoupper()` php function. I have updated my answer code with it.

Comment: why with same code, just mine categories, I got empty response?