# Remove Woocommerce cart quantity selector from cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am trying to remove Woocommerce cart quantity selector from the cart page. I am using the quantity input field on my shop archive pages and it has applied it to the cart page. How can I remove it and not allow the user to change it?

I have tried the following with the code below, researched and found from official Woocommerce docs but it is doesnt apply the rule...

```
function wc_remove_quantity_field_from_cart() {

if ( is_cart() ) return true;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', 'wc_remove_quantity_field_from_cart', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: are the products sold individually? if not, this might give you a problem...

Comment: I have tried this and will really give you a problem. I have added 10, but in cart it has only 1 quantity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were just missing the `$return` and `$product` from your function...The below function will work otherwise with the built in hook.

```
function wc_remove_quantity_field_from_cart( $return, $product ) {

if ( is_cart() ) return true;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', 'wc_remove_quantity_field_from_cart', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: removing 10 and 2 would be less code and same result. Without the need to add `$return` and `$product`

Answer (score 8):

there's a bigger problem in your code than just fixing it.

Instead use this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', 'wc_cart_item_quantity', 10, 3 );
function wc_cart_item_quantity( $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ){
    if( is_cart() ){
        $product_quantity = sprintf( '%2$s <input type="hidden" name="cart[%1$s][qty]" value="%2$s" />', $cart_item_key, $cart_item['quantity'] );
    }
    return $product_quantity;
}
```

this will change the select field into a hidden field. Thus the quantity is there correctly. Unlike changing the `sold individually` property which will make the quantity on the cart just 1.

[image: reigelgallarde.me]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer… It could even have it displayed as a readonly text field type.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code?

```
function wc_remove_all_quantity_fields( $return, $product ) {
    if(is_cart()){
        return true;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', 'wc_remove_all_quantity_fields', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The quantity increment php file has 2 action calls before and after the quatity field.

Check for the sold individually in the action calls:

```
            function woocommerce_after_quantity_input_field() {
               global $product;
               if ( !$product->is_sold_individually() ) 
                   //add your minus icon spinner html code here;
            }


            function woocommerce_before_quantity_input_field() {
               global $product;
               if ( !$product->is_sold_individually() ) 
                   //add your plus icon spinner html code here;
            }
```

Reported at woocommerce  https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/40923