# how to remove the square of Quanity for woocommerce cart page? Have try different themes, but seem like the css/layout tie to woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

how to remove the square of Quanity for woocommerce cart page?  Have try different themes, but seem like the css/layout is tie to woocommerce. The current themes is  twentytwentytwo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9hDB.png)

have trying many elements and disable some css. still can't make it work. please help.

At the same time, use code from
[Remove Woocommerce cart quantity selector from cart page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562595/remove-woocommerce-cart-quantity-selector-from-cart-page)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', 'wc_cart_item_quantity', 10, 3 );
function wc_cart_item_quantity( $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ){
    if( is_cart() ){
        $product_quantity = sprintf( '%2$s <input type="hidden" name="cart[%1$s][qty]" value="%2$s" />', $cart_item_key, $cart_item['quantity'] );
    }
    return $product_quantity;
}
```

will also remove the function of increase/decrease quality. (while just would like to remove the box, not the entire feature.

added: remove the quantity box border in black("input"/stepper without boarder), but keep the increase and decrease quantity function.

added again: with testing url: https://s-qb6as3jh4rw8.eu1.wpsandbox.org/

Comment: Do you just want to remove the quantity box border in black? or an entire quantity box with input so user can not enter qty.

Comment: remove the quantity box border in black,   something like input box without border, reading something like from the web, (not sure if correct terms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code to your active theme style.css file.

```
.quantity .qty {
    border: none !important;
}
```

Or

Add below code to your active theme functions.php file.

```
function add_custom_css{
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .quantity .qty {
            border: none !important;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_custom_css', 10, 1 );
```

[image]

Comment: Share your site URL.

Comment: Hello @Bhautik https://s-qb6as3jh4rw8.eu1.wpsandbox.org/

Comment: What is Access Code?

Comment: In Stackoverflow we can not DM each other directly.